# Instance variables, preventing changes once its value has been set

Tags: ruby, exception, instance-variables

There is a class `Section` (as part of `MyModule` mixin).

Its instance variable `@mark` is initialized to `nil`, and can be changed by an instance method `change_mark` when its current value is `nil`, but not when it's been set to something else. I'm trying to build some protections to prevent the instance variable from being set in such case.

Here's what I have:

```
module MyModule
  class Section
    attr_accessor :id, :mark

    def initialize(id, mark)
      @id = id
      @mark = mark
    end
    def change_mark(mark)
      if @mark != nil?
        message = "Section ##{@id} is already marked. Choose another."
        raise RuntimeError.new(message)
      else
        @mark = mark
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Is raising an error the simplest way to prevent changes to a previously-set instance variable? If not, what can I do?

Comment: Your `initialize` looks like it accepts a certain value `mark`, to which `@mark` is initialized. It is not clear how this goes well with `@mark` being initialized to `nil`.

Comment: @sawa the `mark` from the constructor can be `nil`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I know. But the description "`@mark` is initialized to `nil`" does not make much sense.

Comment: @sawa Well but instance variable _are_ initialized to nil.

Comment: I do not understand why you are mentioning to raise an error. Not doing anything in case the variable is `nil` would be the simplest way. I do not understand why this possibility is removed from consideration.

Comment: @sawa: this is a way to implement a kind of a true constant, which ruby doesn't have.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be that super-strict about not letting users reset the variable, then yes, raise/fail is a good way to go. One note, though: use `mark=` accessor, so that the users won't have to remember using restrictive `change_mark` instead of all-allowing default writer `mark=`.

```
module MyModule
  class Section
    attr_accessor :id, :mark

    def initialize(id, mark)
      self.id = id
      self.mark = mark
    end

    # overwrite generated setter from attr_accessor
    def mark=(mark)
      if !mark.nil?
        message = "Section ##{id} is already marked. Choose another."
        fail RuntimeError.new(message)
      else
        @mark = mark
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Or you could just ignore the new value.

```
def mark=(mark)
  @mark = mark if @mark.nil?
end
```

This way you won't know which line attempted to reset the value and when. But it's quieter. The choice is yours. :)

Comment: Why raise RuntimeError and not StandardError?

Comment: @MarkoAvlijaš: no specific reason. That felt like a better choice at the time. Both work equally well.

Comment: But you are not supposed to catch RuntimeError, so why raise it?

Comment: @MarkoAvlijaš: Aren't you confusing `RuntimeError` with `Exception`?

Comment: Oh right LOL.  I should take a break to clear my head.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest changing the line:

```
attr_accessor :id, :mark
```

To two lines like:

```
attr_accessor :id
attr_reader :mark
```

So your `mark` can be changed only via `change_mark` method, so proper exception is thrown.

With `attr_reader :mark` there is only "getter" method created for your attribute, so you don't have to wary about any other way of setting your attribute value.

Good luck!